# Altium mechanical layers not showing up in layer selection

Tags: altium, footprint, properties

edit: I'm dumb I realized I could just press "l" and manually add in the mechanical layers I need

I have a few .PcbLib documents, and all but one of them I am able to select lines, polygons, extrusions, etc and set them to any layer I want with no problem. In this last document, when I select the "layer" menu under properties it only allows me to select mechanical1. The other options are not there.

Here is a picture of one of the files that works:

[image]

And here is a picture of the issue in question:

[image]

Is this a setting that I changed on accident? All of my other .PcbLib files do not have this issue.

(I am using a 3D model as an example because it only shows mechanical layers but other things like lines and pads also only show mechanical 1)

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't forum where you add "solved" to the title.  If you solved your problem, write an answer and accept it yourself.  That will properly wind up your question so that other people (and the system) know that there's an answer.

Comment: Doesn't make you dumb   ;)   Altium has alotta tools - It takes a while to learn them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved in post: can press "l" to manually add in the mechanical layers